vscode timeline does not show local file history
I did some modifications on a file from vscode. I always do some ctrl+S when i leave vscode. But the file is not up to date. I had a look in the timeline section (see picture) but the last element is a commit i did a week ago. The last modifications after that commit seem to be lost.
I could not retrieve my file from the last save.enter image description here

honestly no idea why this is happening. more info from you is probably needed to figure this out. if you save now, does a new entry get added to the timeline? what if you run Local History: Create Entry in the command palette? what do you see when you run Local History: Find Entry to Restore?

No change in the timeline section if  i make modifications and save. using Local History: Find Entry to Restore,  it shows a version of the file anterior to the last commit.

what about Local History: Create Entry

using Local History Create Entry it adds a new breakpoint but it did not change previous local history. Very annoying, loosing 1 week of work

there isn't enough info to know what happened here. have you modified any of the local storage settings?

@starball i did not make any modifications on local storage. Timeline only keeps tracks of commits
